# Async file download progress not displaying in console window

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace FileDownloadUIClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string[] arguments;
        public Form1(string[] args)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            arguments = args;                
            download();
        }
        public void download()
        {
            if (arguments.Length < 0) { this.Close(); }
            else
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);                    
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(arguments[0]), DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() +".bin");
            }
        }        
        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
            Console.WriteLine( int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString()));
        }
        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Download Completed");
            this.Close();
        }
```

Main method:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FileDownloadUIClient
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1(args));
        }
    }
}
```

This (windows form application) C# program start when passing **file download url** as a parameters.

```
Ex:
C:\FileDownloadUIClient\bin\Debug>FileDownloadUIClient.exe "http://localhost/myfile.mp4"
```

But Download progress or download complete messages are not display in command prompt window.Where is I am wrong?

Comment: What is displayed in the console? What project type is it?

Comment: Project type is windows form application.(it is must)Nothing display in console

Comment: can you show us the `Main` method ?

Comment: [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1(args));
        }

Answer (score 2):

Windows forms applications do not have consoles.

If you want to see console output, change the project type to Console Application.

Comment: It Works!But then come new issues.
 * When GUI program running it will open cmd.exe window

Comment: @Elshan: This behavior is by design.  You can't have half of a console.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is Targeted as `Windows Application Form` then change it to `Console Application` as you need console to display the progress.

---

[image]

Make sure you have Output type `Console Application` it must show progress properly after that !

Comment: Is there any other method to indicate progress in cmd, because this program want both command line and GUI.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show progress but on a Windows Form, consider using the [`ProgressBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) control.  You can't use `Console`, as others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Winform does not offer a console to you by default, if you just want to use "console" for test/monitoring, try:

```
Debug.WriteLine(...);
```

You will see the results in VisualStudio output window.